Help needed with running SLAM package on ROS2
everyone.
I need help running a 3D SLAM package for mapping and localization in a gazebo simulated forest environment.
I am curently making use of the following SLAM package available on GitHub:
https://github.com/rsasaki0109/lidarslam_ros2
I have a drone that has a 3D lidar on board, the point cloud of which I can visualize in RVIZ.
This is the visualization of a test environment with cylinders as objects:

The lidar point cloud output message type is PointCloud2.
My drone publishes the following topics

/scan is published as a topic with a message type of PointCloud2, and the IMU topic is of type Imu. The namespace is /simple_drone
The SLAM package has a lidarslam launch file which I am using to launch the scanmatcher and the graph_based_slam nodes:
import os

import launch
import launch_ros.actions

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    main_param_dir = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration(
        "main_param_dir",
        default=os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory("lidarslam"), "param", "lidarslam.yaml"
        ),
    )

    rviz_param_dir = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration(
        "rviz_param_dir",
        default=os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory("lidarslam"), "rviz", "mapping.rviz"
        ),
    )

    mapping = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="scanmatcher",
        executable="scanmatcher_node",
        parameters=[main_param_dir],
        remappings=[("/input_cloud", "/scan")],
        output="screen",
    )

    tf = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="tf2_ros",
        executable="static_transform_publisher",
        arguments=[
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "0",
            "1",
            "simple_drone/base_link",
            "simple_drone/laser_frame",
        ],
    )

    graphbasedslam = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="graph_based_slam",
        executable="graph_based_slam_node",
        parameters=[main_param_dir],
        output="screen",
    )

    rviz = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="rviz2", executable="rviz2", arguments=["-d", rviz_param_dir]
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription(
        [
            launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "main_param_dir",
                default_value=main_param_dir,
                description="Full path to main parameter file to load",
            ),
            mapping,
            tf,
            graphbasedslam,
            rviz,
        ]
    )

Running the launch file, I get the following message that:

No matter what I try, I am unable to publish a map to visualize in RVIZ:

I feel that the issue lies with the tf between the map and the base_link of the drone.

I need help in trying to figure out if I am setting up anything incorrectly.
Thank you.

Not related to your question, but I recently came across this reference which might be relevant to your forest slam use case.

You need to first solve the graph_based_slam_node error you get when you launch the file:
error while loading shared libraries 

Once you can correctly load the shared library, check again for the tf between map and simple_drone/odom to see if it is published
